# What is the best way to process complex datatypes in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, date, cakephp-2.0

## My Goal:  Replace the Default Cake Datepicker

I *hate* the default CakePHP FormHelper date-picker select elements and I'd like to use jQuery UI Datepicker widget instead.  In order to degrade gracefully, I want to have a date field (enabled with the widget) and a time-picker select box constrained to 15-minute increments.

In case I explained that poorly, here is what it looks like:

[image: date-picker sample]

## My Ideal Solution

To minimize repetition, I want to put the HTML in a layout Element and process it using a Behavior function.  This way I could do something like the following:

*view.ctp*

```
echo $this->element( 'datepicker', array( 'data' => $data ) );
```

*model.php*

```
$actsAs = array( 'Datepicker' );

function beforeSave( $options ){
    $this->parseDatepickers();  //behavior function would alter $this->data
    return true;
}
```

## The Problem

Unfortunately, by the time it gets to the `beforeSave` (or `beforeValidate`) callback, the datepicker & timepicker fields have been destroyed by the model's `deconstruct` function.  `deconstruct` seems to be looking for dates & times to be reported the way FormHelper creates them.

In short, it's looking for:

```
[date_field] => Array
(
    [year] => 2011
    [month] => 11
    [day] => 11
    [hour] => 8
    [min] => 00
    [meridian] => pm
)
```

but instead it's finding:

```
[date_field] => Array
(
    [datepicker] => 11/11/2011
    [timepicker] => 8:00 pm
)
```

And because it doesn't find the structure it expects, I end up with this:

```
[date_field] =>
```

*I know I can have jQuery update hidden inputs with the appropriately-named fields, but this wouldn't degrade well.*

## Current Workaround

What I'm doing, for the moment, is washing the data through my behavior function prior to saving -- but this doesn't feel like the right way to do it:

```
$this->request->data = $this->Event->fixDates( $this->data );
$this->Event->save( $this->data );
```

## So...............

What is the best way to do this?  Putting it in `beforeSave` or `beforeValidate` seems like "the Cake way", but `deconstruct` kills me.  Do I need to extend AppModel and override `deconstruct`?  That seems ugly too.

Comment: Have you tried hooking into `beforeValidate`?

Comment: @deceze yes.  `Model::save()` calls `$this->set()` before it calls any of of the 'before' callbacks. `set` uses `deconstruct`.  Result is the same using `beforeValidate` or `beforeSave` in either the model, overridden appmodel, or behavior

Answer (score 2):

I normally make my date fields as text fields in the view to override the default Form Helper output and then use jQuery date picker (or whatever your alternative picker would be) to set the date:

```
echo $this->Form->input('date', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'datepicker'));
```

This would output a typical  tag rather than all the drop downs.

Then, in my model's beforeSave function, I change the format to MySQL formatted date:

```
$this->data['Model']['date'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($this->data['Model']['date']));
```

(remember to return true in beforeSave)

This works with a proper datetime datatype in the database and it sounds like what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you know a good datetimepicker then?  I'd be content to use a jQuery datepicker/timepicker combination populating 1 input field, but the only integrated plugin I've seen [uses sliders](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) and I'm not terribly fond of it.  [There](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) [are](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) [others](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timepicker/), but they seem to rely on a discreet time field, which brings me back to my original problem of having 2 fields.

Comment: The easiest solution is a 1 field date picker, but if you must have a two field, then why not make the date field hidden, then create a date and time field and have them concatenate their results in the date field when done. All that would happen in javascript and you still end up with a single date field being sent to Cake.